# Surprising numeric comparison results involving NaN in GNU awk (gawk)

Tags: awk, floating-point, nan

Using awk/gawk, I need to perform numeric comparisons involving NaN floating point values. Despite the fact that gawk seems to have correctly converted my user input as a numeric value NaN (i.e. not the string "NaN"), the results of comparisons performed with operators '<' or '>' don't match what I would expect.

**Expectation**:

Comparisons such as `x > y`, or `x < y`, where x is NaN and y is a floating point value (including NaN and +/-Infinity), should evaluate to false. [citation to an IEEE document needed (but [wikipedia NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN) has the table)].

**Actual result:**

NaN < 2.0 == 0, but NaN > 2.0 == 1

The following snippet takes the first field and adds `0` to it to force conversion to integer (as described [in the gnu awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html#Strings-And-Numbers)). It then uses printf to show the type of the variables and expressions (my particular version of gawk doesn't have `typeof()`).

```
$ echo -e "+nan\n-nan\nfoo\nnanny" | awk \
'{x=($1+0); printf "%s: float=%f str=%s x<2==%f x>2==%f\n",$1,x,x,(x<2.0),(x>2.0);}'

+nan: float=nan str=nan x<2==0.000000 x>2==1.000000
-nan: float=nan str=nan x<2==0.000000 x>2==1.000000
foo: float=0.000000 str=0 x<2==1.000000 x>2==0.000000
nanny: float=0.000000 str=0 x<2==1.000000 x>2==0.000000

$ echo -e "+nan\n-nan\nfoo\nnanny" | awk --posix \
'{x=($1+0); printf "%s: float=%f str=%s x<2==%f x>2==%f\n",$1,x,x,(x<2.0),(x>2.0);}'           

+nan: float=nan str=nan x<2==0.000000 x>2==1.000000
-nan: float=nan str=nan x<2==0.000000 x>2==1.000000
foo: float=0.000000 str=0 x<2==1.000000 x>2==0.000000
nanny: float=nan str=nan x<2==0.000000 x>2==1.000000
```

*Running GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1*

Is there a different way/option to have NaNs propagate properly?
I read the page on [standards vs practice](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/POSIX-Floating-Point-Problems.html) which talks about NaN, and I think I'm going about it correctly. I get the feeling NaN is perhaps not super well baked into awk. I couldn't find a reliable way to test whether a value was a NaN, for instance (other than via printf).

Answer (score 3):

**What does POSIX have to say?**
First of all, POSIX allows, but does not require that awk supports `NaN` or `Inf` values. From the [awk IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_18):

> Historical implementations of awk did not support floating-point infinities and NaNs in numeric strings; e.g., `"-INF"` and `"NaN"`. However, implementations that use the [`atof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atof.html) or [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) functions to do the conversion picked up support for these values if they used an ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard version of the function instead of an ISO/IEC 9899:1990 standard version. Due to an oversight, the 2001 through 2004 editions of this standard did not allow support for infinities and NaNs, **but in this revision, support is allowed (but not required)**. This is a silent change to the behavior of awk programs; for example, in the POSIX locale the expression:
>
> ```
> ("-INF" + 0 < 0)
> ```
>
> formerly had the value `0` because `"-INF"` converted to `0`, but now **it may have the value `0` or `1`**.

**How does GNU awk handle such magic IEEE numbers?** The [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/POSIX-Floating-Point-Problems.html#POSIX-Floating-Point-Problems) states:

> - Without `--posix`, gawk interprets the four string values `"+inf"`, `"-inf"`, `"+nan`", and `"-nan"` specially, producing the corresponding special numeric values. The leading sign acts as a signal to gawk (and the user) that the value is really numeric.
> - With the `--posix` command-line option, gawk becomes *"hands off"*. String values are passed directly to the system library’s [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) function, and if it successfully returns a numeric value, that is what’s used. *By definition, the results are not portable across different systems.*

So in short, GNU awk — without the `--posix` option — is **only** able to successfully convert the strings "+nan", "-nan", "+inf" and "-inf" into a floating point representation (See the function [`is_ieee_magic_val`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/node.c?h=gawk-4.1.3)).

Surprisingly, it does not convert `"nan"` and `"inf"`, especially since the string conversion of `"+nan"+0` is a signless `"nan"`

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print "+nan"+0, "nan"+0}'
nan 0
```

*Remark:* when using `--posix`, GNU awk might recognize the strings `"nan"` and `"inf"` as well as others such as `"infinity"` or the completely unexpected,`"nano"` or `"info"`. The latter is probably the main reason why — when not using `--posix` — the sign is paramount and only the strings "+nan", "-nan", "+inf" and "-inf" are recognized.

**How does GNU awk sort such magic IEEE numbers?**

When digging into the source code of GNU awk, we find the following comment for the routine [`cmp_awknums`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/node.c?h=gawk-4.1.3):

> ```
> /*
>  * This routine is also used to sort numeric array indices or values.
>  * For the purposes of sorting, NaN is considered greater than
>  * any other value, and all NaN values are considered equivalent and equal.
>  * This isn't in compliance with IEEE standard, but compliance w.r.t. NaN
>  * comparison at the awk level is a different issue and needs to be dealt
>  * within the interpreter for each opcode separately.
>  */
> ```

This explains the OP's original question why NaN is not following IEEE comparisons and thus `("+nan"+0<2)` is `0 (false)` and `("+nan"+0>2)` is `1 (true)`. *(Remark: we added a zero to the string to ensure a numeric conversion)*

This can be demonstrated with the following code (no `--posix`):

```
BEGIN { s = "1.0 +nan 0.0 -1 +inf -0.0 1 1.0 -nan -inf 2.0"; split(s, a)
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
        for (i in a) printf a[i] OFS; printf "\n"
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
        for (i in a) printf a[i] OFS; printf "\n"
      }
```

outputs the following orderings :

```
-inf -1 -0.0 0.0 1 1.0 1.0 2.0 +inf +nan -nan
-nan +nan +inf 2.0 1.0 1.0 1 0.0 -0.0 -1 -inf
```

If `NaN` would follow the IEEE conventions, it should always appear at the beginning of the list, disregarding the order, but this is clearly not the case. The same holds when using `--posix`:

```
function arr_sort(arr,   x, y, z) {
  for (x in arr) { y = arr[x]; z = x - 1
     # force numeric comp
     while (z && arr[z]+0 > y+0) { arr[z + 1] = arr[z]; z-- }
    arr[z + 1] = y
  }
}
BEGIN { s = "1.0 +nan 0.0 -1 +inf -0.0 1 1.0 -nan -inf 2.0"
        s = s" inf nan info -infinity"; split(s, a)
       arr_sort(a)
       for (i in a) printf a[i] OFS; printf "\n"   
}
-inf -infinity -1 0.0 -0.0 1.0 1 1.0 2.0 +inf inf info +nan -nan nan
```

Note that the string "info" is seen as an infinity while — without `--posix` — it will be converted to `ZERO` (dito for `"inf"`, `"nan"`, ...)

**What is the deal with `("+nan" < 2)` and `("+nan"+0 < 2)`?**

In the first case, a pure string comparison is done, while in the second case the string is forced to a number and a numeric comparison is done. This is similar to `("2.0" == 2)` and `("2.0"+0 == 2)`. Where the first returns false, the second returns true. The reason for this behaviour is that in the first case, awk only knows that "2.0" is a string, it does not check its content, hence it converts `2` to a string.

```
BEGIN { print ("-nan" < 2)  , ("-nan" > 2)  , ("+nan" < 2)  , ("+nan" > 2)
        print ("-nan"+0 < 2), ("-nan"+0 > 2), ("+nan"+0 < 2), ("+nan"+0> 2)
        print ("-nan"+0 )   , ("-nan"+0)    , ("+nan"+0)    , ("+nan"+0)   }
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
nan nan nan nan
```

**How to check for `inf` or `nan`:**

```
function isnum(x) { return x+0 == x }
function isnan(x) { return (x+0 == "+nan"+0) }
function isinf(x) { return ! isnan(x) && isnan(x-x)  }
BEGIN{inf=log(0.0);nan=sqrt(-1.0);one=1;foo="nano";
    print "INF",   inf , isnum(inf)   , isnan(inf)   , isinf(inf)
    print "INF",  -inf , isnum(-inf)  , isnan(-inf)  , isinf(-inf)
    print "INF", "+inf", isnum("+inf"), isnan("+inf"), isinf("+inf")
    print "INF", "-inf", isnum("-inf"), isnan("-inf"), isinf("-inf")
    print "NAN",   nan , isnum(nan)   , isnan(nan)   , isinf(nan)
    print "NAN",  -nan , isnum(-nan)  , isnan(-nan)  , isinf(-nan)
    print "NAN", "+nan", isnum("+nan"), isnan("+nan"), isinf("+nan")
    print "NAN", "-nan", isnum("-nan"), isnan("-nan"), isinf("-nan")
    print "ONE",   one , isnum(one)   , isnan(one)   , isinf(one)
    print "FOO",   foo , isnum(foo)   , isnan(foo)   , isinf(foo)
}
```

This returns:

```
INF -inf 1 0 1
INF inf 1 0 1
INF +inf 1 0 1
INF -inf 1 0 1
NAN -nan 1 1 0
NAN nan 1 1 0
NAN +nan 1 1 0
NAN -nan 1 1 0
ONE 1 1 0 0
FOO nano 0 0 0
```

We can be convinced that the function `isnan(x)` works as expected when investigating the source code of [`cmp_awknums`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/node.c?h=gawk-4.1.3) (added some comments to explain):

```c
int cmp_awknums(const NODE *t1, const NODE *t2)
{
    // isnan is here the C version
    // this ensures that all NANs are equal
    if (isnan(t1->numbr))
        return ! isnan(t2->numbr);
    // this ensures that all NANs are bigger than any other number
    if (isnan(t2->numbr))
        return -1;
    // <snip>
}
```

Comment: String conversion isn't the (only) matter here. Otherwise `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%s\n", (("+nan"+0)<2)}'` and `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%s\n", (("+nan")<2)}'` would return the same value. I believe the string (keyword?) `nan` has a special meaning, at least when dealing with number.

Comment: @oliv updated the answer. The answer was found in the source code.

Comment: @oliv and now I am convinced that there is a bug in awk

Comment: This is all very unfortunate. Such a simple technical issue, complicated by legacy and conflicting standards. I wonder if the discrepancies when sorting arrays containing NaNs are due to the sorting itself not being guaranteed 'stable'. You seem to have an intimate knowledge of awk internals, would you care to recommend how one could, in the absence of a reliable NaN-safe comparison operator, _safely_ determine first if a value is numeric `NaN` before using typical operators i.e. `function isNaN(x) {...}  if isNaN(x) && x > 2.0 ...`?

Comment: @init_js see update. I do not really have deep intimate knowledge of the gawk internals , I just went trough the source code. And the more I am testing, the more the plot thickens. While `"-nan"+0` converts to `"nan"`, `sqrt(-1.0)+0` stays `"-nan"`

Comment: @init_js are your `nan's` the result of a computation or read from an input file?

Comment: @init_js some more information came to light. I have updated the answer.

Comment: The NaNs are read from an input file, which is produced by a tool over which I have control. I use `+nan` as placeholders in the tabular data, which if understand correctly, should be parsed as numeric NaNs in both `--posix` and non-posix mode. In the question here I posted `(x+0) < 2.0` to hopefully reduce the scope of answers (e.g. wrt string, numeric, and strnum types). re: safely identifying NaN values, there are 2^53-1 valid encodings for NaN -- and I wondered whether using `x == "+nan"+0` was a sure-shot way of catching all possibilities. Source code would tell.

Comment: Looking again at your `isnan()`,  I find `"+nan"+0 == "+nan"+0` being true to be just as surprising  as `"+nan"+0 > 2.0` is true. In many languages, `x == x` is a simple test that fails _only_ with NaN. Different language, different rules, but it's not comforting. Using any other placeholder string than "+nan", like "NADA", would yield more predictable results.

Comment: @init_js I checked the source and can assure that the presented `isnan(x)` will work as expected. Disregarding of all possible valid encodings for NaN. I also found some more information on the matter and updated the answer. I hope this helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most concise way (that I could think of) for one to obtain the 4 special values :

> ```
> gawk 'BEGIN { print _-=log(_<_), -_, _-=_, -_ }'
> ```

```
+inf -inf +nan -nan
```

so in terms of indicator functions against their numeric values
-— (sadly, `NaN`s also need a string compare since `+nan == -nan` numerically as far as `awk` is concerned ) :

> ```
>  function    is_inf(_) { return is_negINF(_) || is_posINF(_) }
>
>  function is_posINF(_) { return -_<+_ && (+_)==-log(_<_) }
>  function is_negINF(_) { return +_<-_ && (+_)== log(_<_) }
>
>  function    is_nan(_) { return is_negNAN(_) || is_posNAN(_) }
>
>  function is_posNAN(_) { return (_!~"[-]") && (_)==  (_-=_=log(_<_))  }
>  function is_negNAN(_) { return (_ ~"[-]") && (_)==(-(_-=_=log(_<_))) }
> ```

```
 1  +inf -inf +nan -nan
 2  1 1 0 0 0 0
 3  1 0 1 0 0 0
 4  0 0 0 1 1 0
 5  0 0 0 1 0 1


 8  BEGIN { print __=_-=log(_), ___=-_, ____=_-=_, _____=-_

10      print is_inf(__), is_posINF(__), is_negINF(__),
              is_nan(__), is_posNAN(__), is_negNAN(__)

…       < repeat for the other 3 >       
18  }
```

> *these are by no means all-scenarios encompassing*; **may contain unexpected outcomes for edge cases**